# Is the set of all measurable disks of radius $R$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ a Manifold?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, manifolds

Consider the real plane as $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ be the borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Now define the map $S:\mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$
such that
$$
\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^2 S(x) = \{ y\in\mathbb{R}^2 | (y_1 - x_1)^2 + (y_2 - x_2)^2 \le R \} \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (\star)
$$

for a fixed value of $R$ with $0 < R < \infty$.

Then if $(\star)$ is a well defined function it would be a bijection between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and all the measurable disks on the plane.

My questions are the following:

- **1** If $(\star)$ is a well defined function?
- **2** Is there a topology on $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ which makes $(\star)$ a diffeomorphism onto its image?.
- **3** If so, then is the image of $(\star)$ is a manifold?.

Comment: How are you choosing $R$? And what does the measure theory add to this problem?

Comment: The set of all closed disks is in bijection with $\Bbb R^2 \times [0,+\infty[$ by assigning to any disk the couple (center,radius). (Btw: I agree with the above comment: how are you even choosing $R$ in your construction?)

Comment: Can you name a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^2$ that is not a disc?

Comment: @ElchananSolomon, I updated the question by setting $R$ a finite constant number. I'm using the Borel $\sigma$-algebra because it in the problem I'm studying, I'm interested in integrating on the disks.

Comment: @RafaelRojas As stated, the image of $S$ contains all disks of a fixed size, which doesn't even contain all disks, let alone all Borel sets. So although $S$ is well-defined, it's not a bijection so it cannot be a diffeomorphism. Whether you can topologize the entire $\sigma$-algebra I'm not sure, but the map $S$ is injective so you can identify its image with $\mathbb{R}^2$ and give it the Euclidean topology, making it a diffeomorphism.